# Build the different df from one df based on the ids columns in a df with multiple Nans

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has multiple Nan values. I want to build three different dataframe from it. Here is an example of my df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[10, np.nan, np.nan, 22, np.nan], 'b':[23, 12, 7, 4, np.nan],  'c':[13, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 65]})

     a      b   c
0   10.0.  23.0 13.0
1   NaN    12.0 NaN
2   NaN    7.0  NaN
3   22.0.  4.0  NaN
4   NaN    NaN  65.0
```

I want to assign an id to the df based on this:
from a cell which is not Nan until the next cell, their ids are equal. For example in this df we only have 2 ids (1,2). From row 0-row2 has the id=1, and the others have id=2.
So, based on this I want to build the following df.

id and column a:

```
    id  a
0   1   1
1   2   22
```

id and column b :

```
    id  b
0   1   23
1   1   12
2   1   7
3   2   4
```

id and column c:

```
    id  c
0   1   13
1   2   65
```

Could you please help me with that? Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify why for dataframe  for column `b` is the last row with id `2`?

Comment: Surely the `id` value for `b` should be `1 23; 2 12; 3 7; 4 4`?

Comment: @nick No. The first column determine the id. We have two non Nan value in the first columns, so we only have two ids.

Comment: @AndrejKesely The first column determine the id. We have two non Nan value in the first columns, so we only have two ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate your `id` based on non-NaN values of `a`, then create your outputs by dropping rows which have `NaN` values in their respective columns:

```py
df['id'] = df['a'].notna().cumsum()
df_a = df[['id','a']].dropna()
df_b = df[['id','b']].dropna()
df_c = df[['id','c']].dropna()
```

Output:

```
>>> df_a
   id     a
0   1  10.0
3   2  22.0
>>> df_b
   id     b
0   1  23.0
1   1  12.0
2   1   7.0
3   2   4.0
>>> df_c
   id     c
0   1  13.0
4   2  65.0
```

If required, you could `reset_index` on the results to make the index sequential starting from 0 e.g.

```
df_a = df[['id','a']].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   id     a
0   1  10.0
1   2  22.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to create `id` with [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then slice:

```
for col in df:
    print(col)
    out = (df.assign(id=df['a'].notna().cumsum())
             .loc[lambda d: d[col].notna(), ['id', col]]
          )
    print(out)
```

Output:

```
a
   id     a
0   1  10.0
3   2  22.0
b
   id     b
0   1  23.0
1   1  12.0
2   1   7.0
3   2   4.0
c
   id     c
0   1  13.0
4   2  65.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
id_ = df["a"].notna().cumsum()
for c in df.columns:
    print(df.loc[df[c].notna(), [c]].assign(id=id_))
```

Prints:

```
      a  id
0  10.0   1
3  22.0   2

      b  id
0  23.0   1
1  12.0   1
2   7.0   1
3   4.0   2

      c  id
0  13.0   1
4  65.0   2
```